# Flutter, Firebase: retrieving data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question. I have an app that allows users to save posts by clicking an icon. Posts are saved in Firebase inside a collection called "saved", this collection is inside another collection called "posts". This is a saved sample post:

[image]

Here is an example of an unsaved post:

[image]

***The question is, how do I retrieve only the saved posts?***

Any sample code you write can help me, or even suggest an idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal by multiple ways, but I think since you are trying to get all collections in your database that is names `saved`, consider trying `Collection Group` it would help get all documents inside any `saved` collection in your database, for more information you can check:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query